# condition case statement and check if record exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following scalar function, this function compares values between one user and another if they match then it returns true otherwise false.

The function is as follows:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN us.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS does_data_match
   FROM [User].[User_Profile] up
   INNER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  [user].[User_Settings] us
   ON us.UserId = @UserId1 
   AND d.Height between ISNULL(us.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us.HeightTo, d.Height) 
   AND up.Age between ISNULL(us.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us.AgeTo, up.Age)
   AND up.Gender = ISNULL(us.Gender, up.Gender)
   WHERE up.id = @UserId2
   ORDER BY up.id ASC
```

The problem I have with this function is occasionally User.User_Settings doesn't contain a record for @UserId1 so by default it should return 1 allowing @UserId2 to contact them, but it returns 0 due to the case statement, I have switched the 0 and 1 around in my case statement but doing so caused the function to return incorrect results when @UserId1 exists in the settings table.

I have tried to condition it with an If statement to check if @UserId1 exits in the user settings table if it does then run the case statement, else select 1 (true) as default.

But for some reason it wont allow me to have an If statement within the scalar function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Update

This is what my casestatement looks like when I wrap it in a IF Statement

```
IF EXISTS(Select Userid from [user].[User_Settings] where UserId = @UserId1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN us.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS does_data_match
        FROM [User].[User_Profile] up
        INNER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  [user].[User_Settings] us
        ON us.UserId = @UserId1 
        AND d.Height between ISNULL(us.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us.HeightTo, d.Height) 
        AND up.Age between ISNULL(us.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us.AgeTo, up.Age)
        AND up.Gender = ISNULL(us.Gender, up.Gender)
        WHERE up.id = @UserId2
        ORDER BY up.id ASC
    END
   ELSE
    BEGIN
      return 1
   END
```

But as mentioned I get the following error message Incorrect syntax near if

Comment: just to clarify - some records have UserID as null, and some do not have it period?

Comment: @ElenaDBA Users have the option to add a record to the settings table, if they do then UserId will be linked to the user that inserted the record and I will then compare UserId1 to UserId2 and return true of false, otherwise return 1 by default if no record exists for UserId1

Comment: I'm not aware of a limitation against using IF in a UDF.   Please post the entire create/alter function code.   Maybe the syntax error is right before the IF.   Or maybe it's because you have a RETURN in your ELSE clause, but not in your IF clause.

Answer (score 3):

Use an IF condition first to check if the @UserId1 exists in Settings table. IF NOT, return the required value. If the record does exists check if both the ID's match and return the required value.

This should be simple and easy to handle.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckFunction]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@UserID1 int
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ReturnCode BIT

IF (@UserID1 = 1)
BEGIN
SET  @ReturnCode =  1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @ReturnCode = 0
END

RETURN @ReturnCode
END

GO
```

Executing the function:

```
SELECT [dbo].[CheckFunction] ( 0 ) --returns 0 (expected)

SELECT [dbo].[CheckFunction] ( 1 ) --returns 1 (expected)
```

Comment: I've tried conditioning the case statement, but it doesn't allow me to have an if statement wrapped around it

Comment: What I mean is to use the CASE only when you have records in the settings table. If @UserId1 doesn't exists in Settings you do not have to execute your SQL at all.

Comment: This is a scalar function, it gets executed within the query and I pass in UserId1 and UserId2 and its inside this scalar function I tried to write the if statement to check if UserId1 exists in the settings table, if it does then I execute the case statement, otherwise return 1 by default.  But the scalar function doesn't allow me to have an if statement inside it

Comment: Can you please check the edited answer above and let me know if this is inline with what you want...

Comment: I've just tried your update, I get an error on my select statement saying "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to the client"

Comment: Your query is logically incorrect:
You need to have SELECT @Var = TOP 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86610/discussion-between-darshan-bi-dw-and-coderatchet).

Comment: Can you please share the resultant correct query on the board so that others would be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like is user was not entered into usersettings, the id will always be null, but if user was entered, then the ID will never be null, so just try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
CASE WHEN us.UserId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @UserID2 END AS does_data_match
FROM [User].[User_Profile] up
INNER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN  [user].[User_Settings] us ON up.ID=us.UserID
WHERE up.ID = @UserId1 
AND d.Height between ISNULL(us.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us.HeightTo, d.Height) 
AND up.Age between ISNULL(us.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us.AgeTo, up.Age)
AND up.Gender = ISNULL(us.Gender, up.Gender)
ORDER BY up.id ASC
```

Comment: User_Profile is liked by up.Id = us.UserId I've just tried your answer and it returns null

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do. Try my update

Comment: I've added an update to the question, showing my situation when I add a If statement around the cas statement

Comment: so the select should grab all the records from userprofile and corresponding records from usersettings. If record exists in both userprofile and user settings, the select returns 1, else, if user does not exist in settings, it returns 0. Is that correct? If so, what is @UserID2?

Comment: Just saw your update. So in that case UserID will always be NULL in UserSettings when user was not enterd there and if user was entered it will never be null

Comment: this functionality is to limit who can contact you, so UserId1 fills out the mail settings saying he/she wants to be contacted by people who are of a certain age range / height range and gender. this information is then saved into the settings table.  UserId2 comes along and wants to view UserId1 profile when he/she requests UserId1's profile I then call this function, passing in the UserId1 and UserId2 I then compare the settings UserId1 has specified to UserId2 profile / details and if he/she falls into the category UserId1 has specified I then return 1 else 0

Comment: But as mentioned UserId1 may not fill in the settings allowing what ever user to contact them so on this occasion as UserId1 doesn't exists in the settings table, so by default I will return 1

Comment: Your update still doesn't work, I have two records currently in the table and it should return 0 for both as both profiles are different.  If does on the other hand work when  a record doesn't exists.

Comment: could you post your sample data?